# Form Submit - Open New Tab at same time

Tags: forms, hyperlink, tabs, submit

I have a contact form on my website. I'm using a free bootstrap template that I've been editing and configuring because I don't know much about coding.

I want a new tab to open and go to a specific website when the user hits the submit button (so both submit the form, and take them to a new web page). How can I do that?

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" target="blank" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add in the

```
action="/newpage.php" method="post"
```

so in your example, it would look like:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="/newpage.php" method="post"  novalidate>
```

Hope that helps... Note the /newpage is the page (wherever it is) which will process your POST request.

Comment: The form sends me an email. I'd like to be notified when a user submits the form. But I also want the submit button to take them to a website to make a donation. This donation page is not hosted on my site.

Comment: So to be clear, the form - is it saving on YOUR website, then redirecting to the donation site OR is the form supposed to save on the donation website?

If YOU are saving the info, THEN directing, I would suggest that you have a POST php page which handles the SAVE request & emails you the info, which then redirects the user to your donation external link...

Please confirm the workflow above, and I can help with above logic.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the javascript like this.
then will open new tab as you said

```js
function func1(){
  window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" onsubmit="func1()" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And also you can add action property to form tag.
then if you click the button then will open the new tab as your request, and then will send request to file you specified in action property.
if your purpose is only to open new tab, and don't need to submit form, then please add

```
return false
```

at the end of func1 function in my code

Comment: Do I create a new javascript file or add it to the existing one?

Comment: if you don't want to create new javascript file, then please add above javascript file into your html but you have to wrap with <script></script>

Comment: like this
<script language="javascript">
function func1(){
  window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
}
</script>
add this to below of </body>

Comment: I did this but the form didn't submit at all now. And the new tab did not open.

Comment: please check whether you also added onsubmit() into form tag.

Comment: onsubmit="func1()" check you added this code into form tag.